# Ограничение на ввод даты в DataGrid

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

У меня есть таблица Timetable, которая представлена в виде DataGrid. В нем есть столбец "Date". Я хочу чтобы можно было вводить в этот столбец только дату не раньше текущей. Вот что я пробовал сделать, но это не работает. Подскажите как можно модифицировать код

```
private void timetableDataGridView_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
        {
            string headerText = timetableDataGridView.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].HeaderText;

            if (!headerText.Equals("Date")) return;
            DateTime date;
            if (!DateTime.TryParse(e.FormattedValue.ToString(), out date) && date > System.DateTime.Now)
            {
                timetableDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = "attention";
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
        }

        void timetableDataGridView_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            // Clear the row error in case the user presses ESC.   
            timetableDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = String.Empty;
        }
```

Comment: Посмотрите метод `DateTime.Compare`

Answer (score 0):

Используй для сравнения **DateTime** метод **CompareTo**

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.datetime.compareto?view=netframework-4.8